# Look I've marked it

Tags: word-usage

I wrote my first letter on my pillow case,  so will it be okay to use:

> Look I've marked it (with my initial). 
>   (I wrote the first letter of my name on it)

Does the sentence sound natural and can the part in the brackets be dropped?  If yes, then will it sound natural?

Answer (score 1):

It is ok... but the situation is weird. Why would you write your initial on a pillowcase? That's not normal. Why do you need to explain the fact that you wrote your initial?

Anyway, does the person know your initials? Are they expecting you to write your initials on your linen? If so, then "Look. I've marked it" makes sense. In fact just "Look!" is probably enough, since they can see what you've done.

On the other hand if they don't know what you are up to, there is no reason for them to know that "marked" means "marked with my initials". You have to know what is going on in the other person's head to know if "Look. I've marked it" is going to make sense to them or not.

You can "initial" as a verb meaning "to write your initials"

Comment: Can it simply be: "Look,  I've marked it" Or does it have to be:"Look I've marked it with my initial"

Comment: I know that it sounds weird but something had happened (well,  that was in fact really weird,,  weirder than this whole marking thing)

Answer (score 0):

If you were in some kind of institution where all the pillowcases are bundled together in the wash but you wish to make sure that your own pillowcase is returned to you then you could say 'I've put my initial on it (so that I know I will get it back)'.